# Claims added in Controller not found in following ActionFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, claims-based-identity, actionfilterattribute

When I add a claim to an identity in a controller on

```
HttpContext.User.Identities.First(
    i => i.AuthenticationType == IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)
```

with

```
Addclaim(new Claim(type, value))
```

and try to retrieve that claim from the ActionExecutingContext in my custom actionfilterattribute on the next request, why is it not present there? I'm using the code below to access the claims:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class ClaimActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var claims = context.HttpContext.User.Claims;

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is your authentication based on an Authorization token? Are you updating the token after you add the claim?

Comment: Adding claims to Identity should be before SignIn

Comment: @WaelAbbas The claims that are working were added _before_ SignIn, so that's probably the mistake I made.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add claims to Identity before SignIn.

Answer (score 1):

Claims are persisted via the auth cookie, so they are only "refreshed" at sign in. If you add or update a claim, you need to log the user out afterwards. You can then choose to either sign them back in automatically or force them to re-authenticate manually.